# First jQuery script won't run, what's wrong

Tags: jquery, fadein

This is my first jQuery script, which won't run. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Furry Friends Campaign</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/my_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "clickMe">Show Me the Furry Friend of the Day</div>
        <div id = "picframe">
             <img src="images/furry_friend.jpg">
        </div>
            <script src = "scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#clickMe").click(function() {
                    $("img").fadeIn(1000);
                    $("#picframe").slideToggle("slow"); 
                });
            });
        </script>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have added updated my jQuery version to 1.7 and have removed extra spaces around the assignment operation "=":

My problem continues. The styling is being applied, but when I click over the script nothing happens, nor does the "click" thumb icon appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Furry Friends Campaign</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/my_style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="clickMe">Show Me the Furry Friend of the Day</div>
        <div id="picframe">
             <img src="images/furry_friend.jpg">
        </div>
            <script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#clickMe").click(function() {
                    $("img").fadeIn(1000);
                    $("#picframe").slideToggle("slow"); 
                });
            });
        </script>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS style sheet:

```
#clickMe {
    background: #D8B36E;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 205px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000
    }

#picframe {
    background:#D8B36E;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 205px;
    display: none;
    border: 2px solid #000
    }
```

Comment: What is this `</a>` doing in your markup? How exactly is the script *not running*?

Comment: Can you check if you have jquery-1.6.2.min.js is linked correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js` is actually working and not a 404 by using [firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/).

But the problem is likely the spaces around your "=" in the script tag, it should look like this:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you hiding the `img` first?

I don't see your css, so I can't tell.

But if you are not starting with the `img` hidden, you won't be able to use `.fadeIn()`